# SemidefiniteOptimization stops and does not work

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I am trying to make the following code work:

```
M = {{x11, x12, x13}, {x21, x22, x23}, {x31, x32, x33}};
SemidefiniteOptimization[
  1, 
  VectorGreaterEqual[{M, 0}, {"SemidefiniteCone", 3}], 
  Flatten[M]]
```

However, it just stops and does nothing. Essentially, the SDP problem would consist on finding the first matrix $M$ that is positive semidefinite.

Comment: Does `VectorGreaterEqual[{M, 0}` impliy semidefiniteness of `M`?

Comment: I think it does, at least that is the translation of the symbol appearing in the reference. https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SemidefiniteOptimization.html

Comment: Indeed, this quits the kernel. Must be a memory issue. This must not happen. Please contact Wolfram Support about this.

Answer (score 1):

Up to the documentation,

> The matrices Subscript[a, j] must be symmetric n *n matrices.

Therefore, `M` should be changed to become a symmetric matrix. The following works.

```
M = {{x11, x12, x13}, {x12, x22, x23}, {x13, x23, x33}};
SemidefiniteOptimization[1, VectorGreaterEqual[{M, 0}, {"SemidefiniteCone", 3}], {x11, x12, x13, 
x22, x23, x33}]
(*{x11 -> 20.9077, x12 -> 0., x13 -> 0., x22 -> 20.9077, x23 -> 0., x33 -> 20.9077}*)
```